# What is eWASM and why is it the direction for the next version of the EVM?

Tags: evm, protocol, ewasm, wasm

eWASM was [first proposed in EIP 48](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/48) with performance advantages over the EVM.  Are there other advantages since the EIP was written in 2015?

The [initial benchmarks](https://github.com/wanderer/wasm-to-llvm-prototype/blob/master/results.md) are also gone and are there any current benchmarks that show how much faster eWASM is over the current EVM?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97908/discussion-on-question-by-eth-what-is-ewasm-and-why-is-it-the-direction-for-the).

Comment: Would like to accept an answer for this, but doing so currently would be misleading.

Answer (score 5):

The project is still ongoing: https://github.com/ewasm/evm2wasm

WASM seems more secure, also, webassembly is backed by Google, Apple and Microsoft, the community is also active, it's gonna be a widely used platform. So embrace WASM will be a really good choice.

I'm also looking for the benchmark ...

Answer (score 0):

ewasm, an improved version of the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) is envisaged,
which will make code execution faster, hence resulting in an overall performance gain. Speed is kinda nature of web assembly

`ewasm` will be the execution engine for sharding when sharding comes online. It will still execute all the code written for `evm`.

Another benefit is you could write smart contracts in other languages,  such as C, C++, and Rust and compile it down to ewasm.